# Boy who can learn languages if he hears just a few words...mom is kidnapped...YA book title?

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, languages

I read part of a book about a boy who could speak a language if he heard just a few words. He and his mother play a game where they slide on the floor in socks while she plays the radio and he learns new languages. However, his mom is later kidnapped and he goes undercover in illegal trade as a translator. It was a YA book that was part of a series about talented kids. I think one of the other books had a kid who was a talented thief and left a ribbon behind whenever they successfully took something. Anyone know it?

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Is this set in contemporary times? Something medieval? Prehistoric? Victorian?

Comment: Given the radio, probably relatively contemporary in retrospect...

Comment: Well, the story sounds interesting, I hope someone can answer. Does he have siblings?

Comment: You may try to look in TVTROPES WARNING https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Omniglot

Comment: The mysterious Benedict society?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't Chris Archer's *[Alien Scream](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0671014846)*, is it?

The only details I could find that were at all the same were the languages, it was a kid, and other kids are involved. Not clear if they have talents, too.